# client_id and scope must both be provided to initialize OAuth

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I'm working off [Google Sheets API Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) and have run into an authentication issue with `gapi.client.init()`.

Here is the code that's giving me issues:

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
var CLIENT_ID = "50m3-cle3nt-1d.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var API_KEY = "AIzaN0tRe4lLyAn4pIk5y";

// Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function() {
        // doesn't matter.
    })
}
```

I can't get the `init()` call to work, and I get the error as in the question title even if I try to call `init()` on its own inside the console:

```
> k = gapi.client.init({ ... })
client_id and scope must both be provided to initialize OAuth
```

What am I missing in the call to `init()`?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Update the value of `var CLIENT_ID`. To get the credentials, follow the Step 1 - d to i in this [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). You can not call `init()` on its own because it is dependent on this function `handleClientLoad()` which loads the auth2 library and API client library.

Comment: I was using a valid `CLIENT_ID`, I just wasn't going to paste it here. But thanks for the note that `init()` will fail on its own.

Comment: Anything new about this? I'm having the same problem with the Calendar API. I have my API Key and the web client ID. They are both correct. Also I have `discoveryDocs` in the init call :S

Comment: Hmm, this isn't solved despite having simmered for 2 years. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have the same problem with google calendar API

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same problem.
In the `initClient` function I replaced `gapi.client.init` to `gapi.auth2.init`
and it worked.